# How do I display both the first and last elements of an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to return the first and last elements of an array.

```
def first_and_last(a)
  a.first
  a.last
end
```

but it's only displays the last element and when I put the plus sign it just adds the elements. I want it to print something like this[1,3]. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

```
['cat', 'dog', 'pig'].values_at(0,-1)
  #=> ["cat", "pig"]
```

Comment: That might return duplicates or double `nil` for arrays of 1 and 0 length, but otherwise, right on.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to create a new array with two elements which are the first and last of the argument, respectively:

```
def first_and_last(a)
  [a.first, a.last]
end

first_and_last([1,2,3]) # => [1, 3]
first_and_last(1..100) # => [1, 100]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def first_and_last(a)
   return a.first, a.last
end
```

or

```
def first_and_last(a)
   return a[0], a[-1]
end
```

Comment: You can ignore the return call. `return x, y` can be written as `x, y`

Comment: @Santhosh I don't think so, do you test?

Comment: @pangpang, sorry, it has to be `[x, y]`. But yes, you can ignore the return call.

Comment: @Santhosh `x, y` as a statement-expression is invalid syntax. The `,` is *special* in the `return ..` grammar.

Answer (score 0):

```
def first_and_last(a)
  return [a.first, a.last]
end
```

in your code you are not returning any value in ruby if you are not return value then last line after execution return automatically. So you need to return like abobe

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Array, Set, ActiveRecord, or some other collection, then you should do the following:

```
def first_and_last( collection )
  [ collection.first, collection.last ]
end
```

Note:  There's no need of the **return** keyword because the last executed statement within a Ruby method is what gets returned to the caller of the method.  Next, **parameters to your method should be intention revealing**.  That is, it should be easy for others to understand what is it.  In this case, it's a collection (i.e. Array) which responds to both **first** and **last** messages.

Think different and code well,

-Conrad